# A conjecture on p-divisibility of Bernoulli numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, bernoulli-numbers

Is anyone aware of the history of the following conjecture on the $p$-divisibility of (the numerators) of Bernoulli numbers?

CONJECTURE: For $p$ an odd prime, and $k$ even with $2 \leq k \leq p-3$, $p$ cannot divide both $B_k$ and $B_{p-k+1}$.

This conjecture is mentioned in Ohta's paper: *Companion Forms and the structure of $p$-adic Hecke algebras.* (see Example 3.3.4 on p. 25)

As far as I am aware, this is the only instance of the conjecture in literature. I believe I have a proof using companion forms and Ribet's proof of Herbrand-Ribet. I am currently writing it up and want to give proper references. Thanks

Comment: You might try emailing Ken Ribet.  He will almost certainly answer you, and he's tremendously knowledgeable.  

Comment: I think that the paper of Frank Calegari on Eisentein primes, in Compositio, also discusses this conjecture.  (This is a somewhat
vague memory, so I apologize in advance if I'm wrong.)

Comment: And if you do email Ribet, you might want to mention this MO question, I think he has registered here already (see user 5131).

Comment: By the way, this would be a very nice result, considering its application to the structure of Hecke algebras and to Iwasawa theory.

Comment: @Pete : i have emailed Ribet and am awaiting his response.

Comment: @Emerton: Thanks for the reference. I glanced through FC's paper and he has used Bernoulli numbers but I couldn't find anything about the exact problem I was referring to. Maybe I will look at the paper more carefully.

Comment: @unramified: Have you finally heard from Ribet ?  And have you written up your proof of Ohta's conjecture ?